# Alternative functions for setMaxDate(new Date(today)) in ie11

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any alternative functions to set the max date ?

```
var today = new Date();
Text.setMaxDate(new Date(today));
```

The above function goes in error when executed in ie11 and working in chrome

Comment: What is the value of `today`? And what is the value of `new Date(today)`?

Comment: updated code . Value of today is Sat Mar 09 2019 17:25:30 GMT+1100 (Australian Eastern Daylight Time)

Comment: what is Text.setMaxDate??